# What is a "Covering Function"?

Tags: functional-programming, function, definitions

In [Idris2](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2), I will sometimes get an error telling me that a function "is not covering", which is apparently distinct from it not being total (and I do understand what a total function is).  I have not been able to find a reference to a "covering function" anywhere on Wikipedia, Wolfram, or any Stack Exchanges (except [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72114989/how-can-i-convince-idris-that-my-function-is-covering)).  When I *do* find references to it (in some Idris question), it is not explained what it actually means -- apparently everyone there just knows.

What I *do* find is something called a "covering **space**", which is related to a "covering map", but apparently a covering map is always continuous, so that can't be what Idris is talking about, since no function from ℕ to anything (for example) can be continuous.

Comment: Based on that other answer, it just means that a definition by cases doesn't cover all possible cases.

Comment: @MaxNew That's what it looks like, but I don't know why it wouldn't just be called partial/non-total if that's what it's talking about.

Comment: There are other reasons a function might be partial (such as if its definition uses a partial function). This is more informative, it tells you there is something specifically wrong with your patterns.

Comment: @MaxNew Ah!  That makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer [here](https://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/reference/syntax-guide.html#totality).

@MaxNew was right; it's just a part of totality.  A function definition is not covering if there is a possible input which has not been handled in the pattern matching.